# question on Independent probability

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose that the probability of being killed in a flight is $p_c=\frac{1}{4\times10^6}$. Assume that different flights are independent. if a businessman takes 20 flights per year, what is the probability that he is killed in a plane crash within the next 20 years?

At first, I thought probability of being killed each time is $p_c$ and they are independent, 20x20=400 flights, then shouldn't we have $p_c^{400}$ to be the probability?

But the solution to the question is deduced by first looking for the probability of him surviving the next 20 years. I don't quite get this, why can't $p_c^{400}$ work?

Comment: $p_c^{400}$ would be the probability of every one of those 400 flights crashing.

Comment: ok that makes sense now, thanks!

Comment: Also you can check that $p_c^{400} < p_c^1$, so your first thought means that the businessman is less likely to be killed than one who only travel by flight once ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$p_c^{400}$ is the probability of all 400 flights crashing. Note that for the man to die, only one of 400 flights needs to crash. We can calculate the probability that the $k^\text{th}$ flight crashes(and all before it don't) as
$$P(k^\text{th} \text{ crashing})=(1-p_c)^{k-1}p_c$$
The probability of any one flight crashing is now given by
$$\sum_{k=1}^{400}(1-p_c)^{k-1}p_c=p_c\cdot\frac{(1-(1-p_c)^{400})}{1-(1-p_c)}=1-(1-p_c)^{400}$$

This is actually better understood by calculating the probability of him surviving. Since to survive for the next 20 years, the man has to survive *all* flights he takes. The probability of this is $(1-p_c)^{400}$. Thus the probability of him dying is in fact $$P(\text {dying})=1-(1-p_c)^{400}$$

Exactly the same as we calculated before.